# How to disable some options in "Select" component of Material-UI like in "Autocomplete"?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

is there is any way to disable some options in the `Select`  component like in `Autocomplete`

PS: the option is in an array

```
 <FormControl variant="outlined">
        <InputLabel>States</InputLabel>
        <Select native
          defaultValue=""
          // value={value}
          onChange={inputEvent}
          label="States"
        >
          {fetchedStates.map((states, i) => (
            <option key={states + i} value={states}>
              {states}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

[image]

Comment: You already have the docs open and you just have to look at the implementation. The answer is already in the picture you provided. You have to add getOptionDisabled.

Comment: well my options are in an array so there no given method to disable specific option in `select`

Comment: Are you using a `native` `Select`? You aren't showing the `native` prop in your example, but `<option>` tags are only valid as children for `native` `Select` (for non-native, the children should be `MenuItem` elements).

Comment: soory ,can you check again

Answer (score 11):

The way to do this for `Select` is to add the `disabled` property to the `MenuItem` (shown for the "Twenty" `MenuItem` in the example below).

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Age"
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem disabled value={20}>
            Twenty
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit disabled MenuItem]

For a native `Select`, you instead use the `disabled` prop for `<option>`:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Age"
          native
        >
          <option aria-label="None" value="" />
          <option value={10}>Ten</option>
          <option disabled value={20}>
            Twenty
          </option>
          <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit disabled option]

If the options are in an array, you just need to have some way of determining which options should be disabled. The example below shows one way of doing this where the option data contains whether or not the option should be disabled.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

const options = [
  { value: 10, label: "Ten" },
  { value: 20, label: "Twenty", disabled: true },
  { value: 30, label: "Thirty" }
];

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Age"
          native
        >
          <option aria-label="None" value="" />
          {options.map(option => (
            <option value={option.value} disabled={option.disabled}>
              {option.label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit disabled option]

Comment: sorry, I didn't add that but the options is an array? can you please check again the above question

Comment: The <option> tag also has a disabled prop: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: @KALITA I have added more examples.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Note that adding `disabled` in `MenuItem` doesn't add `disabled` attribute to the DOM element which make the test failed when you test the disable state of the element (`.toBeDisabled()`).

Comment: @NearHuscarl On `MenuItem` it adds `aria-disabled="true"` to the DOM as well as the `Mui-disabled` CSS class. The DOM element is an `<li>` and `disabled` is not a supported attribute for `<li>` elements.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Oh thanks, I didn't aware of [that](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#disabled-elements). It makes sense now.